# "Segmentation Error" in monerod on TAILS in previously synced 0.14.0 GUI. Am I screwed and need to start over?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui

The wallet was synced and everything was fine about 2 days ago

Comment: Can you post some of the log messages please?

Comment: @jtgrassie - This was deemed a blockchain corruption.